# Better user of Html Helpers to format text?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have my profile model with these properties

```
public string FullName {get; set;}
public string Email {get; set;}
```

And I'd like the text to be displayed like this:

> John P Doe (someemail@notreal.com)

Currently I do this:

```
<div class="row section-head-bold">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Profile.FullName)
    @Html.Raw(" (")@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Profile.Email)@Html.Raw(")")
</div>
```

Is there a better/cleaner way?

Comment: `<div class="row section-head-bold">@string.Format("{0} ({1})", Model.FullName, Model.Email)</div>` (or add a property in your view model)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `@item.Profile.FullName (@item.Profile.Email)` will also work. Or make a `NameAndEmail` model class containing these properties, and create a a Display Template for it... plenty of solutions here, you just happen to have chosen about the most clumsy syntax to do this.

Comment: Can't you can just remove the parts you don't really need..? like this (most obvious I suppose): @item.Profile.FullName (@item.Profile.Email).. Means, from the looks of it, it seems you don't need html helpers at all to achieve what you want.

Comment: you should pre-process in the action

Comment: this is one of those... "I can't think of a better way  so I'll ask Stackoverflow"... just *try* thinking. and I like @ken-d-timothy perpsective, but the question is weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the best way would be to create another property such as:

```
public string NameEmail {
    get {
        return String.Format("{0} ({1})", FullName, Email);
    }
}
```

However in case you need to use a separate style for FullName and Email, you can make your own custom HtmlHelper to achieve this. I have done this recently for a DateRangeDisplayFor which requires me to process the dates and display it with custom HTML structure and CSS classes. I have quickly modified the codes for your scenario and you can definitely modify this further to suit your needs.

**HtmlHelper to display more complex HTML structure with custom CSS classes**

```
public static MvcHtmlString NameEmailDisplayFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property1,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property2,
    object htmlAttributes = null, bool useStyle = true)
{
    // Get the meta data of the properties
    ModelMetadata metadata1 = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(property1, htmlHelper.ViewData),
        metadata2 = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(property2, htmlHelper.ViewData);

    // get the data from db. If null, display N/A
    string name = metadata1 == null ? "N/A" : metadata1.Model.ToString();
    string email = metadata2 == null ? "N/A" : metadata2.Model.ToString();

    // build the HTML container tag and the sub-tags
    TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("label");    // parent wrapper
    var nameLbl = new TagBuilder("label");       // child label
    var emailLbl = new TagBuilder("label");      // child label

    // assign the model value to the labels
    nameLbl.InnerHtml = name;
    emailLbl.InnerHtml = email;

    // if useStyle is set to true, set custom CSS classes
    if (useStyle) {
        nameLbl.AddCssClass("label label-default");
        emailLbl.AddCssClass("label label-primary");
    }

    // apply inline HTML attributes (if any)
    if (htmlAttributes != null)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in htmlAttributes.ToDictionary())
            tag.Attributes.Add(attribute.Key, attribute.Value.ToString());
    }

    // add the child labels to the parent HTML wrapper
    tag.InnerHtml += nameLbl.ToString();
    tag.InnerHtml += emailLbl.ToString();

    // build the final MVC HTML string to be returned
    return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

And now you can use the HTML Helper in this way:

```
@Html.NameEmailDisplayFor(model => Model.Name, model => Model.Email)
```